# Highcharts Export Server Now importing External Pattern Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts Export Server and its an external server. I am sending a JSON request to it and want to get the image out there on the screen. I have the sample working if I just draw graph on the screen as shown in the fiddle below with the Graph as it looks like.
[image]

[Normal Chart can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/2gd6zt6L/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
    stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    color: {
      pattern: 'https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/Dots_Large.png',
      width: 10,
      height: 10
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    color: {
      pattern:'https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/Grid.png',
      width: 10,
      height: 10
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    color: {
      pattern:'https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/Bricks.png',
      width: 15,
      height: 15
    }
  }]
});
```

---

But when I try to host my server to print this using **Highcharts Export Server**, I get a graph which is nothing but Blank Lines as shown below:-

[image]

[Edited Code Here with Export Server](http://jsfiddle.net/6h8o16g0/337/)

```
    $(function () {
    $("#b").click(testPOST);

    var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';

    function testPOST() {

        var optionsStr = '{"chart":{"type":"bar"},"title":{"text":"Stacked bar chart"},"xAxis":{"categories":["Apples","Oranges","Pears","Grapes","Bananas"]},"yAxis":{"min":0,"title":{"text":"Total fruit consumption"}},"legend":{"reversed":true},"plotOptions":{"series":{"stacking":"normal"}},"series":[{"name":"John","data":[5,3,4,7,2],"color":{"pattern":"https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/Dots_Large.png","width":10,"height":10}},{"name":"Jane","data":[2,2,3,2,1],"color":{"pattern":"https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/Grid.png","width":10,"height":10}},{"name":"Joe","data":[3,4,4,2,5],"color":{"pattern":"https://sampleproject-shivkumarganesh.c9users.io/img/Bricks.png","width":15,"height":15}}]}';
        dataString = encodeURI('async=true&type=jpeg&width=400&options=' + optionsStr);

        if (window.XDomainRequest) {
            var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            xdr.open("post", exportUrl+ '?' + dataString);
            xdr.onload = function () {
                console.log(xdr.responseText);
                $('#container').html('<img src="' + exporturl + xdr.responseText + '"/>');
            };
            xdr.send();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                url: exportUrl,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('get the file from relative url: ', data);
                    $('#container').html('<img src="' + exportUrl + data + '"/>');
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('error', err.statusText)
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Now, this seems to be weird because I am not able to understand why the export server is not able to render my images that I send a JSON Request.

I have no clue what I should do to make it work and print the use the PNG images to fill the graph. I am doing this in order to print and get the graphs with patterns for people who suffer from color blindness. We need to export it to PDF after getting a png.

**NOTE:-**
The Stack is as follows:-

1. [Highcharts Export Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-export-server)
2. [pattern-fill plugin highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/extension/pattern-fill/)
3. Few PNG images

Comment: The 'normal chart' example that you posted doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that the links to images are broken.

Comment: @KamilKulig Actually its not broken. My server went down. I have restarted it out! Please look into it now.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Here I use image pattern encoded in base64 and it worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/hmgnhkdh/ But when I did the same thing in your example the pattern is not visible (although there're white spaces where the columns should be): http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mvs1rvw8/ You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: @KamilKulig This worked for me. But i am getting random file names. Is there a way to customize file names using Http SErver??

Comment: Notice that this file is stored on the Highcharts server - there's no possibility to customize it.